# Build error using dlib library in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dlib

This is the first time I started use `Dlib library`.
I make a project and include `dlib's face detection example cpp`.
I have already linked to `pthread` and `-std=c++1` into my project.
I have already included the folder path which has `dlib` folder inside.
I have already included `source.cpp` into my project.
When I build, I have errors from this `source.cp`p as

```
15:43:22 * Build of configuration Debug for project ObjectDetectionDlib *
make all
Building file: ../src/ObjectDetectionDlib.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -DGXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X -I/home/nyan/Softwares/Dlib_Lib/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/ObjectDetectionDlib.d" -MT"src/ObjectDetectionDlib.o" -o "src/ObjectDetectionDlib.o" "../src/ObjectDetectionDlib.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/ObjectDetectionDlib.cpp

Building file: ../src/source.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -DGXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X -I/home/nyan/Softwares/Dlib_Lib/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/source.d" -MT"src/source.o" -o "src/source.o" "../src/source.cpp"
../src/source.cpp:7:41: fatal error: ../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp: No such file or directory
#include "../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp"
^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/source.o] Error 1
```

What is wrong? I use g++/4.8 as compiler.

Comment: I need to include X11 and pthread lib inside Library linker.